# understanding how my GPU/CPU compares to a computational protocol to estimate runtime?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I have access to a machine that has 112 CPUs (Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8180 CPU @ 2.50GHz) and 4 GPUs (GeForce RTX 1080) that I would like to use to run a published computational protocol for reasearch that I do. It would be useful to have an estimate of how long it'll take to run.

The protcol tells me this:

"The timing for running the protocol was estimated on a cluster with 640 cores (64 cores per CPU node) and 50 GPUs using 60 cores for each job"

I googled my CPU and found that it has 28 cores. So do I have 112*28 (3,126) cores? I don't know what 'CPU node' means and if it that is equivalent to a 'CPU'?

When I googled by GPU, it said I have 2560 'Cuda Cores'. I am guessing they have GPUs as good if not better than mine, but it seems strange they are only using 60 cores? This is in the context of training a deep learning model.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have 112 real CPUs and not just 4 CPUs with 112 (4 * 28) cores in total?

Comment: [This](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/120496/intel-xeon-platinum-8180-processor-38-5m-cache-2-50-ghz.html) answers your question. Your system has 2 of those processors, each processor has 28 cores, for a total of 56 cores and 112 threads. I have no idea where your quoted text comes from but they used the word cluster, which I am guessing, your system isn’t configured as a cluster

Comment: @StarCat I ran the following command:

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo

and got 112 entries, but I am not sure if those are unique CPUs or if they are as Ramhound says.  I did find the link Ramhound sent (which is where I got my 28 core number from).

Comment: The CPU you listed has a recommended customer price of $10k and pulls 205W each. Somehow, I don't think you spent over a million dollars on your system or have a 23KW energy budget.

Comment: @doneal24 It is a supercomputer in my lab, this is not something I built or ordered.

Comment: In deciphering `/proc/cpuinfo` you might look at the number of unique entries for `processor:`. You'll likely see only proc 0 and proc 1. Next is `physical id` and `siblings`. The former is the core number on the processor and the second is the thread on the core.

Comment: @DK_chemistry My comments we not very helpful to a new user - it's been a bad morning but you did not deserve my answers.. It sounds like you really have something like [this](https://www.thinkmate.com/system/gpx-xs8-24s3-4gpu). A really nice workstation but now a supercomputer.

Comment: @doneal24 thank you for the kindness. I am in really over my head in a PhD project involving computation with a background exclusively in synthetic chemistry. I know I am asking dumb questions, but I am just so, so stressed and so behind on my project and totally in over my head.

Answer (score 1):

The general process for estimating runtimes on a large problem is to run a few trials with much smaller datasets of different sizes. You can then extrapolate to a rough estimate of the runtime for the full dataset. You might run into issues of memory limitations, cache limits, process locking, etc. that will affect the full runs in ways that don't impact small cases.

The algorithms used by the software will also affect scalability. Are the threads tightly coupled with shared memory and frequent memory or data locks? Alternative may be that it uses a large number of essentially independent threads. The first doesn't scale well, the second does. If the process is I/O bound, throwing more compute resources will not help.

Looking at other systems may be helpful but are not definitive. In addition to the number, type, and speed of the processors you need amount and speed of memory, type of disks (spinning, ssd, nvme), network interconnects, and other processes that my be running on the systems.

Basically, only somebody familiar with the particular program and your dataset will be able to answer your questions.